# Connected one-dimensional CW complex and homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Prove that connected one-dimensional CW complex X has $\pi_n(X)=0, n \ge 2$.
This is a problem from my exam, I tried to use the cellular approximation theorem but didn't solve it. Professor said it is very easy. Any help?

Comment: Do you have the theorems on universal covers?

Comment: No, I don't have. Can you define it, I will search for proof?

Comment: Well, if the prof said it was easy and you don't have these results, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Also, I guess you could ask the prof?

Comment: Yes, but I want to get more ideas

Comment: It is indeed "very easy" if you have the right machinery, such as universal coverings. Otherwise, it is hard. Your professor likely forgot that universal coverings are not yet covered in the class.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you write that solution, it can be helpful later

Comment: @stranger it would help if you included what theorems you have learned so far.

Comment: You cannot do this with just cellular approximation. What exactly does it mean for $f:S^n\to X$ to be cellular? Only that $f(x)$ is a $0$-dimensional cell for a $0$-dimensional cell in $x\in S^n$ (typically we would have a single such cell in $S^n$). Regardless of the choice of CW structure on both sides. That's it. Not much. Maybe your professor incorrectly assume that the $n$-th skeleton of $X$ is a point or something?

Comment: I will, in a day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof. I will be using Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" as a reference.

1. The universal covering space of every connected graph is a connected graph (Lemma 1A.3). Every simply-connected graph is a
   tree (p. 86). Every tree is contractible (pretty much by the definition used by Hatcher). See Section 1.A for basic definitions and properties of trees. Hence, the universal covering space of every connected graph is contractible.
2. Every contractible space has trivial homotopy groups (since the latter are homotopy-invariant).
3. If $X, Y$ are path-connected, $p: X\to Y$ is a covering space, then $p$ induces isomorphisms of homotopy groups $\pi_i(X)\to \pi_i(Y)$ for all $i\ge 2$, see Proposition 4.1.

Now, we can finish: Let $Y$ be a connected graph, $X\to Y$ its universal covering. Then $\pi_i(X)=0$ for all $i>0$ and, therefore, $\pi_i(Y)=0$ for all $i>1$.  qed